# Property binding not working after travel to different screen and coming back to the same screen

Tags: angular, angular6

I conditionally doing show and hide my grid using  `[hidden]="notshowGrid`". where `notshowGrid` is a class level variable.
This works fine when I stay on same screen, but  it fails when I travels to another screen and I come back to same screen, my grid is not rendering. After debugging I found that my variable  `notshowGrid` is getting updated in .ts file but, that is not reflected in DOM. Still it is showing the old binding. For updating this `notshowGrid` variable I am updating it in subscribe call.

I have already tried change detection `detectChanges()` and `markforcheck()` methods.

```js
Onbuttonclick(){
doOperation(arguments).subscribe(
                (resp: Processlaunch[]) => {
                  const uprowdata = resp;
                  this.notshowGrid = false;}}
```

```css
#feesGrid{
    width: 1094px; height: 380px; margin-top: 15px
}
```

```html
  <div  [hidden]="notshowGrid" id="Grid">
           
            <ag-grid-angular #agGrid 
            class="ag-theme-balham" 
            [columnDefs]="columnDefs" 
            [rowData]="rowData
            ></ag-grid-angular>
        </div>
```

I need to show that grid again with the property binding, after coming back to this screen again.

Comment: where is this happening `this.migsvc.doOperation....`? in ngOnInit? and what is `this.selecteddata`? a binding? sth coming from the router?

Comment: doOperation () is happening on button click event. this.selecteddata is just a class level variable

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to set the property `notshowGrid` in `ngOnInit`

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.notshowGrid = true;
}
```

When the subscription will then overwrite the property.

Comment: Hi Rias, thanks for the update. But this solution is not working for me.

Comment: Could you please extend your example above with the relevant methods, class definition etc?